# Sharing an Apple Calendar with a Google Calendar User

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I use the built-in Apple Calendar application.  My significant other uses Google’s calendar.  Is there a good way for us to share one specific calendar between the two of us on these separate apps so that I can continue to use the normal Mac Calendar app?  I really would like to not have to have two calendar apps if possible.  I poked around in the Mac calendar settings and didn’t see a way to share one calendar without having to add her account (which I don’t want to do).  Thank you in advance for any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to her Google calendar if all you want is for the events to show up for you. Easy enough to have her create a read-only link for you - and you can do the same for an iCal calendar (https://www.imore.com/how-publicly-share-calendar-your-iphone-and-ipad).

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, as it is really close to what I actually did not long after posting this question.  I have a Gmail account that I actually use quite a bit.  So, since I already had a Google account, I already had their calendar by default.  I simply created a calendar, shared it with my significant other, then added the Google calendar to my iCal account.  So we actually now share a Google calendar, but it displays on my iCal app and for her, it displays on her Google calendar app.  If I add events to my iCal under that calendar, she gets them on her device, and vice versa.